# Formula for combinations with equally spaced points?

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, combinations, binomial-coefficients

How do I calculate a specific value on this triangle array without doing it manually? https://i.stack.imgur.com/C03lM.jpg

Please no sigma notation! I've already got it, what I'm really looking for is a pretty formula like nCr that doesn't make my calculator cry.

These numbers are the ways you can place P objects in H slots, under the condition that the objects MUST be equally spaced from each other.

The points columns increase like so: (0) + 0 + 0 + 0 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 5 + 5 + 5...       with the additions ticking up every (H-1) rows. This was the example for H = 4.

Here's a diagram for H = 6 and P = 3 https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWooI.png

Comment: username checks out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that we should consider each possible spacing individually. When the spacing is 0, the block of dots take up $P$ spaces, so there are $H-(P-1)$ ways to arrange the dots. Likewise, when the spacing is 1, there are $2P-1$ spaces occupied, so $H-2(P-1)$ ways to arrange the dots.

The number of possible spaces is clearly $\lfloor\frac H{P-1}\rfloor$ so set this quantity equal to $k$. So, our formula is $$kH - \frac{k(k+1)}2\cdot(P-1)$$So, our final formula is$$\lfloor\frac H{P-1}\rfloor H - \frac{\lfloor\frac H{P-1}\rfloor(\lfloor\frac H{P-1}\rfloor+1)}2\cdot(P-1)$$

P.S. This formula fails for 1 dot as spacing doesn't matter, so our analysis fails. This case can be handled manually.

P.P.S. I generated your matrix [here](https://tio.run/##fVDLboQwDDzjr/ANm0cRbaVKldif6HG1h0oNEEAOCulhv56azRbRPTQne2Y8M8p8Db2Tl3X9Mi32bjLL7KyEBem2FBhXfofEtkh3smmw3qDEm/DtJR5CMmITR6yqXVuqFH6FYxb58g@djRmNec1V9QywFQnuI3grHUmBk5Eu9FuaqP0SPAnfyiihI56au@TQRyAx02IOSIppRlFXxkPOBWDWlEBKPg1ah84p6ksv@XlvMBSvjK3zOKAV9J/SGaqL@o0vzLDh9gHX0EfX3cyq2dH88OHKDfxP1rr@AA)

Comment: DAMN HOW'D YOU DO THAT??

Comment: thank you so much don, you terrify me